# Show the new table rows after 1 min automatically using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with 100 rows of data which is displaying 10 rows at a time having pagination also. My question is, i want to show the another 10 rows without clicking on the pagination number. Like that it should be repeat continuously once it done again it come to first just same like the railway indicator which show the new trains / upcoming trains vice versa.

Guys if know the answer please help me, but don't mark as duplicate / irrelavant ...

Thanks in advance

```
 <table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table bulk_action">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="headings">
                       <th class="column-title">S No</th>
                      <th class="column-title">Connection Number</th>
                    <th class="column-title">Received By</th>
                    <th class="column-title">Date</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                  <tr class="even pointer" dir-paginate="list in oporderlist| filter:search|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:10">
                      <td class=" " >{{$index+1}}</td>
                      <td class=" " >{{list.connectionno}}</td>
                      <td class=" " >{{list.receivedBy}}</td>
                      <td class=" " >{{list.createdAt|date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
                <dir-pagination-controls
   max-size="3"
   direction-links="true"
   boundary-links="true" style="float:right" >
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: What method do you call for pagination? Provide some code.

Comment: for pagination i have used the dir-pagination directive

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Check out [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). All you have to do it store the current page, and in the interval function add 1, and if it reaches the maximum pages, set it to 1 back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the numPages is generated dynamically. Instead try this code which will resolve your problem. Here the code goes..

1. first calculate the length of the list

   var len=$scope.oporderlist.length
2. later get the itemsperpage value

   var pgsize=--itemsperpage_value--
3. var numpages1=$scope.oporderlist.length / pgsize
4. as % gives remainder and / gives quotient, get the numpages1 value with math.floor(numpages1) which will give you the exact pagination value.

   var numpage=Math.ceil(numpages1)
5. now you can use this,

   $scope.currentPage=($scope.currentPage % numPages)+1
   // here assign $scope.currentPage=1 at top

So just mix up all this values and its done. More any query, happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Nitin Agarwal. It was woks great. Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

Add a `current-page` attribute to your `<tr>` with the dir-paginate directive, and then call `$interval` from your controller code.

So in your HTML:

```
<tr class="even pointer" current-page="currentPage"
    dir-paginate="list in oporderlist| filter:search|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:10">
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
var numPages = 10;

$interval(function() {
  $scope.currentPage = ($scope.currentPage % numPages) + 1;
}, 10000)
```

Plunker edited from the dir-paginate basic example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3NjpOehzXN9rNV9fsAh?p=preview

Comment: great... Thanks a lot @Fissio. But i dont know the value of numpages which we be generated based on no. of records in that list

Comment: Then you'll need some extra logic inside the interval to determine if the next page has content to show :)